# how to setup multiple automated workflows on aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-workflow

We're trying to use AWS Glue for ETL operations in our nodejs project. The workflow will be like below

1. user uploads csv file
2. data transformation from XYZ format to ABC format(mapping and changing field names)
3. download transformed csv file to local system

Note that, this flow should happen programmatically(creating crawlers, job triggers should be done programmatically not using the console). I don't know why documentation and other articles always show how to create crawlers, create jobs from glue console?

I believe that we have to create lambda functions and triggers. but not quite sure how to achieve this end to end flow. can anyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: I guess you can use the boto3 library to achieve this scenario, though I have some doubt 1. did glue create a new crawler for every single upload? 2. did logic inside the glue script changes for every upload? (or does it require to have a new script for every upload?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Achyut. I guess we can use the same crawler for every upload but, I think we have to create a new job for every upload because, for every upload, a new table will get created in the catalog and we have to provide a table name in the job script to process that transformation or we can pass table name via job parameters dynamically so that we can use single job for multiple uploads. But, I don't know how this rocket science actually works.

Comment: I believe glue is such an overrated service by aws enthusiasts. it can only transform XYZ to ABC only. what if our data consists another format? we have to create another jobs and map those fields having no flexibility pretty bad.

Comment: I guess you have to think in a different way like Create different folders inside the S3 bucket to group the same formatted files, then according to the folder name you can trigger respected jobs with Lambda on S3 multipart upload. (If you know all possible file formats and file metadata for glue catalog table) or you can also use EMR.

Comment: how about new table name on every upload, we have to pass table name to job right? is that possible or do we need to create new job for every upload?

Comment: I suggest if possible you should pass the table name to the job and when the entire logic of the job changes you have to trigger the appropriate glue job. (Glue is used when your input data's metadata is the same for all times)